# search.php from a database for jqueryui autocomplete multiple remote widget

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I want to use jqueryui's autocomplete multiple remote widget. I've downloaded it from the website. It has a search.php page to retrieve data remotely. What I'm asking is that by default it is using array() of PHP of some already given values but I want to use it to retrieve data from a database as the user types the query.

search.php looks like this:

```
<?php

sleep( 3 );
// no term passed - just exit early with no response
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ;
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
// remove slashes if they were magically added

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
$items = array(
"Great Bittern"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
"Little Grebe"=>"Tachybaptus ruficollis",
"Black-necked Grebe"=>"Podiceps nigricollis",
"Little Bittern"=>"Ixobrychus minutus",
"Heuglin's Gull"=>"Larus heuglini"
);
$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11)
        break;
}
// json_encode is available in PHP 5.2 and above, or you can install a PECL module in earlier versions
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

instead of this, I want the $items things to be from a database's (say my_db) table (say my table is named users) and I want to extract name field from this table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to this and only just learning about this myself, so please don't shoot me down if I'm wrong, but:;

-> Do you not just want to run a mysql query as opposed to building an array inside the script?

So something like:

```
$items = mysqli_query($database_connection, "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE column_name LIKE '%$q%'");
```

Like I said I am very new to this so this may be completely wrong, but I am just trying to help!

Good Luck!